# Expressing the taylor's theorem via integrals for the residual

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is twice continuous differentiable and $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$ why do we have that: $ \nabla f(x+p)=\nabla f(x) + \int\limits_0^1 \nabla^2 f(x+tp)p dt$ ??

$\nabla^2f(x)$ is the Hessian matrix of $f$ at the point $x$

Comment: Could you elaborate on your notation ? Especially the meaning of $\nabla^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mean Value Theorem to the rescue! If $g\colon \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ is a $C^1$ function, then $$g(x+p) - g(x) = \int_0^1 \nabla g(x+tp)\,{\rm d}t$$
See lemma $1$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions) for example, for a proof. We apply that to $g = \nabla f$, to get: $$\nabla f(x+p) - \nabla f(x) = \int_0^1 \nabla^2f(x+tp)p \,{\rm d}t,$$as wanted.

Comment: I don't understand the proof of lemma 1 in wikipedia. Why $g_i'(t)$ is expressed by the sum of partial derivatives of $f$? Why don't we simply use a chain rule and $g'(t)=Df(x+th)*h$ as it is claimed in the statement of the lemma?

Comment: It is because the proof in wikipedia chose to do everything in coordinates. I don't see any fault with your reasoning - I actually agree that it is cleaner. We'll have $g(1) - g(0) = {\rm d}f(\gamma(t))(\gamma'(t)) = {\rm d}f(x+th)(h)$.

Comment: Cool, I saw it pretty clear a few seconds later after I posted it hahahaha. Thanks!

Comment: It happens to me all the time!